# Laravel 4.2 Array to String conversion error

Tags: php, laravel-4, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to assign a value to $table property in my Model, based on the URL string. There I am getting "Array to string conversion" error. Below are code level details. Can someone please help? Thanks.

I have coded my model __constructor() as shown below.

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Disaster extends Eloquent {

    use UserTrait,
        RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table;

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function __construct($disasterArea, $disaster = "flood") {

               $this->table = $disasterArea . '_' . $disaster;

    }

}
```

I am trying to pass required values while Model instantiation from my controller as shown below.

```html
class DisasterController extends \BaseController {

    public function getFloodTweets($floodArea){
        $flood = new Disaster($floodArea, "floods");
        $floodTweets = $flood->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('tweets')->paginate(10);
        $floodAreaUc = ucfirst($floodArea);
        return View::make("disaster.floodTweets",['title'=>"$floodAreaUc Flood",'floodTweets'=>$floodTweets,'floodArea'=>$floodAreaUc]);
        
    }
        
    }
}
```

that means if I trigger an URL like **www.example.com/floods/city** my model should build the table as 'city_floods' which is the naming convention we are following. 
And also, I observed table name is being build correctly but throwing this error. And strange thing is my code works fine when I hard code this table name. i.e.

$this->table = "city_floods" works fine but 
$this->table = $disasterArea . '_' . $disaster do not. I don't understand what is the difference. Can someone please suggest where I am doing wrong.

I working on UBUNTU 14.04 with Laravel 4.2 framework.

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Try logging the variables in `__construct` before you assign it to the table. Then you can see what exactly is being passed.

Comment: @aynber you mean to display the variables?

Comment: Yes. `Log::info($disasterArea);` will write the variables to your log file, which is usually stored in app/storage/logs .

Comment: ok. I logged Log::info($disasterArea); and Log::info($disaster); variables.I can see them as two dimensional arrays.

[2016-05-06 13:10:31] production.INFO: assam [ ] [ ]

[2016-05-06 13:10:31] production.INFO: floods [ ] [ ]

Comment: They're actually strings. The `[][]` is what it puts at the end of all log lines. Is the error message coming from that particular line of your code?

Comment: I have added error screen shot to my question. Can you please see if you get some clue

Answer (score 0):

Well You cannot pass the data in that way to the eloquent model because the original abstract eloquent model have the first parameter as `array`! and it will try to put it in this way.

**EDIT**

As you can see on your screen shot - the model is resolving somewhere with a `newInstance` method what means that it trying to put (propably) an empty array into you string varible.

**The solution**

The best option is to split the logic into few Disaster Models that extends the main `Disaster` model and resolving them from factory like that:

```
class UsaFloodDisaster extends Disaster
{
    protected $table = 'usa_flood';
}

class FranceFloodDisaster extends Disaster
{
    protected $table = 'france_flood';

}

(...)

class DisasterFactory
{
    public function make($area, $disaster = 'flood')
    {
        $className = ucfirst(camel_case($area.'_'.$disaster));

        return app($className);
    }

}
```

then your controller would looks like:

```
class DisasterController extends \BaseController {

    public function getFloodTweets($floodArea){
        $flood = app(DisasterFactory::class)->make($floodArea, "floods");
        $floodTweets = $flood->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('tweets')->paginate(10);
        $floodAreaUc = ucfirst($floodArea);
        return View::make("disaster.floodTweets",['title'=>"$floodAreaUc Flood",'floodTweets'=>$floodTweets,'floodArea'=>$floodAreaUc]);

    }
}
```

Comment: ok I tell you why I am doing this. We are building a blog kind of application where we show posts regarding disasters in different places/countries. For that I need to access multiples tables. And I dont want to create new Model for each table. Can you suggest is there any proper alternate way to handle all tables in just one Disaster.php model?

Comment: Of corse I'll write above.

Comment: This is what I understood. I will have two files one with original Disaster.php model and another with solution you have given. From my controller I need to always access the factory class from second file to build my table names. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Almost... You will hav emany files (for every table one) of modeles that have  parent: `Disaster` - and you will call them throught the factory - it's a design pattern you can read about it in web.

Comment: No. I am trying to avoid multiple files. how is it different? Anyways I tried switch statement inside my model to build  the table name. I don't know if it is effective way, but it served my purpose as of now :) . Thank you.